# Cone with height $9$ cm and radius $3$ cm is filled at a rate of $1.2~\text{cm}^3$. Find the rate of change when $h=3$.

Tags: calculus

A cone with radius $3$ cm and height $9$ cm is filled with water at a rate of $1.2~\text{cm}^3$. Find the rate of change of the height of the water when the height of the water is $3$ cm.

I differentiated both sides to get $$\frac{dV}{dt}= \frac{1}{3} \pi \cdot 2(3)~\frac{dh}{dt}$$ Solving for $dh/dt$ I got $5.23599$. My textbook says to use similar triangles but I didn't, I am wondering if there is another way to solve of the rate of change of the height of the water at $h=3$?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to use MathJax.

Comment: The reason you are supposed to use similar triangles is to express the volume as a function of the height of the cone before you differentiate, assuming that you wish to find the rate at which the height of  the water is changing, which you have not explicitly stated.

Comment: Yes, the rate a which the height of the water is changing is what the question asks for. But when i use similar triangles I get r=1 because r/3=3/9 but in my textbook it has h/2 so you can eliminate r from the volume equation.

Comment: It should be $r/h = 3/9 \implies r = h/3$.

Comment: I assume you meant to write the rate in cubic centimeterrs per second, or per millsecond, or ... some time unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ V =\dfrac{\pi}{3}r^2 h $$

Note that there are two terms when you differentiate a product.

$$ \dfrac{dV}{dt} =\dfrac{\pi}{3} (2r\dfrac{dr}{dt} h + r^2 \dfrac{dh}{dt})\tag1$$

If $\alpha $ is semi-vertical angle (constant) of cone then by similar triangles of differential growths $(dr,dh)$ and quotient rule differentiation

$$\dfrac{dr/dt}{dh/dt} =\dfrac{r}{h}= \tan \alpha \tag2$$

I assume you have been asked to use similar triangles in order to appreciate that there is proportion between $(r,h)$ and their differentials $ (dr,dh)$ as shown.

Plug into (1) for $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$ from (2) as other quantities are known, in order to find out $\dfrac{dh}{dt}$.

To find $dV/dt$  $ (r=1,h=3) $ .. should be finally plugged into (1)

alternatively from the above we can write $r$ items into $h$ items to directly obtain $ ( t= \tan \alpha) $

$$ \dfrac{dV}{dt}=\frac{\pi}{3}(2ht\dfrac{dh}{dt} th+h^2t^2\dfrac{dh}{dt}) =\pi h^2 t^2\dfrac{d h}{dt} =\pi r_{max}^2 \dfrac{dh}{dt}= \pi \dfrac{dh}{dt};\,\, dh/dt= \frac{1.2}{\pi} \tag3 $$

EDIT1:

Using the disc method of finding differential volumes for integration we have at start as commented by Ross Millikan:

$$ dV = A dh =\pi r^2 dh,\, (dh/dt) = (dV/dt)/(\pi r^2) = \frac{1.2}{\pi} $$ 
obtained directly ***regardless of profile*** of the rotated solid. If grey shaded vessel has same top area (comparing with a conical vessel with its apex pointing down inverted) then also the same level/drain rates relation holds good. It is independent of second order volume quantities, differential triangle similarity is conceptually all built-in, what was calculated needlessly roundabout.

[image: Any shape]

Answer (score 0):

The volume of a right-circular cone is given by the formula
$$V = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$
The volume is a function of two variables.  If we differentiate with respect to time, we obtain
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{2}{3}\pi rh~\frac{dr}{dt} + \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2~\frac{dh}{dt}$$
We wish to solve for $dh/dt$ given $dV/dt$ and $h$.  However, we do not know $r$ or $dr/dt$.

However, we can relate $r$ and $h$ by using similar triangles to eliminate $r$ from the equation and write the volume as a function of $h$.  Consider the diagram below.

[image: cone_partially_filled_with_water]

By similar triangles,
$$\frac{r}{h} = \frac{3}{9} = \frac{1}{3} \implies r = \frac{h}{3}$$
Hence, we can express $V$ as a function of $h$.
\begin{align*}
V(h) & = \frac{1}{3}\pi\left(\frac{h}{3}\right)^2h\\
     & = \frac{1}{27}\pi h^3
\end{align*}
Differentiating implicitly with respect to time yields
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{1}{9}\pi h^2~\frac{dh}{dt}$$
Since we are given $dV/dt$ and $h$, you can now solve for $dh/dt$.

If we had instead used the equation
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{2}{3}\pi rh~\frac{dr}{dt} + \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2~\frac{dh}{dt}$$
we would need to find $r$ and $dr/dt$.  To do so, we use similar triangles to obtain the relationship
$$r = \frac{h}{3}$$
which allows us to calculate $r$.  Differentiating with respect to time gives
$$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{1}{3}~\frac{dh}{dt}$$
We use similar triangles since we need to know the relationship between $r$ and $h$ in order to substitute for the variables in the equation relating $dV/dt$ and $dh/dt$.

Comment: How exactly did you produce your diagram? What software or tools specifically? I am interested for personal use.

Comment: @Decaf-Math  I used the [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) drawing program tikz.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler is to note that when $h=3$ cm the radius is $1$ cm.  The area of the water is then $\pi$ cm$^2$ so the rate of rise is $\frac {1.2}\pi$ cm/sec

Comment: Simpler answer yes, The main task was also to employ similar triangles.

Comment: Which I did to get the radius from the shape of the cone.

Comment: I am not sure understood this. You should get same result for a cylinder, a cone or a paraboloid bowl  of $(r,z) $ dimensions at   [ base, middle , top edge] = $  [(0,0), (1,1), (2,4)] ? $

Comment: Yes, the result only depends on the area at the moment.  If you add a volume $dV$ of water you raise the level $dV/A$.  The slope on the sides makes a second order correction.

Comment: Phew yeah ! That's how one integrates volumes of revolution by assembling differential discs, right? Thank you!

Comment: That is correct.